# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '<attribute-name>' , while testing Django UserModel

Tags: django-models

I am experiencing a very annoying problem, I would appreciate your help.
I will explain the problem:
I have a user-model that I run unit tests on.
The tests fail time and time again because of the problem that it does not recognize the attributes at all.
I would very much appreciate a solution if anyone has one.
Attaching the relevant code.

**the model:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser,
    BaseUserManager,
    PermissionsMixin
)


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """manager for users"""
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """create save and return a new user"""
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """user in the system"""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

**the tests:**

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class ModelTests(TestCase):

    def test_create_user_with_email_successful(self):
        email = 'test@example.com'
        password = 'testpass123'
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
           email=email,
           password=password,
        ) 

        self.assertTrue(user.check_password(password))
        self.assertEqual(user.email, email)
        
    def test_new_user_email_normelaized(self):
        sample_emails = [
            ['test1@EXAMPLE.com', 'test1@example.com'],
            ['Test2@example.com', 'test2@example.com'],
            ['TEST3@EXAMPLE.COM', 'test3@example.com'],
            ['test4@example.COM', 'test4@example.com'],
        ]

        for email, expected in sample_emails:
            user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(email, 'sample123')
            self.assertEqual(user.email, expected)
```

**the problem:**

```
ERROR: test_create_user_with_email_successful (core.tests.test_models.ModelTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/core/tests/test_models.py", line 16, in test_create_user_with_email_successful
    self.assertTrue(user.check_password(password))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'check_password'

======================================================================
ERROR: test_new_user_email_normelaized (core.tests.test_models.ModelTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/core/tests/test_models.py", line 29, in test_new_user_email_normelaized
    self.assertEqual(user.email, expected)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'email'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.313s

FAILED (errors=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UserManager` is not returning anything that's why you are getting `None` object when you are creating user.

You can use replace the below code with your `UserManager` and that will fix all your test cases.

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """manager for users"""
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """create save and return a new user"""
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email.lower()), **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Here I am doing `email.lower()` because `normalize_email` function only normalizes string before `@` that means it returns `Test2@example.com` as it is instead
of `test2@example.com` and `TEST3@EXAMPLE.COM` as `TEST3@example.com` which is not what you are expecting here.

Comment: What a coincidence... I found the problem and uploaded it before I noticed you answered..
Thank you!
By the way, I really failed the test in the second case because the method is normalized only the domain...
Thanks for the quick response and solution!!

Comment: Good to know, can you please mark the question solved?

Answer (score 0):

Ok... so after a long time of trying to find the problem, it turns out it's really simple.
The problem was that no value was returned from the instance of the UserManger, so the object returned NoneType. And of course it's attributes were not identified.
I added a `return user` at the end of class and everything got identified back again.